# script to renice processes

Tags: bash, minecraft

basically, i have a computer which doesnt have the power to run minecraft well as is. i want to write a script which i can run on starting minecraft which will renice all the processes to 15 and then renice the two processes minecraft (java) sets up to -20 so they get more Cpu time. Im not very good at this kind of script. i cant use PID of the processes as they change every time, can someone give me pointers?

so far i have

```
renice -n 18 -u aphael
renice -n 15 -u root
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: are you by any chance running the script as someone else than root?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: no i'm the only user and i'm a sudoer

Comment: when i tried run in terminal, it flashed and dissapeared. i added a wait but nothing happened onscreen -edit i tried again and got this renice: failed to set priority for 1000 (user ID): Permission denied
renice: failed to set priority for 0 (user ID): Permission denied

Comment: I would imagine that if you're renicing the minecraft processes to -20, then these small increases to other processes are unlikely to make a significant difference

Comment: Are you sure its a CPU bottleneck you're running into?  What does `top` say?  Perhaps you need more RAM or your disk IO is slowing you down?

Comment: im getting an SSD soon to speed IO up, and minecraft quite comfortably runs in 100mb of ram when i give it up to a gigabyte, whereas the CPU is quite old.

Comment: i know most of the processes are quite small but when you have 1000 of them jostling for CPU space and most of them are useless (bluetooth, update manager) it seems a waste